# Create a .NET Core Nuget package to autogenerate c# classes

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, auto-generate

I have a .NET Framework project (A) which generates an exe which takes html file as input and outputs an autogenerated C# class file (like a template of sorts). The `.csproj` of A looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>ProjectA</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="ProjectA.exe.config">
  <ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In project B, we're using the exe like this: (part of csproj of project B)

```
<Target Name="_EX_MyGenerateFile_cs" Inputs="MyHtml.html" Outputs="$(O)\MyGeneratedFile.cs" Condition="'$(BuildingOutOfProcess)' != 'False' AND '$(BuildingProject)' == 'True'" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" Command="<path to projectA exe> MyHtml.html $(O)\MyGeneratedFile.cs" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" Command="if errorlevel 1 echo $(ERR_MSG) Unable to compile MyHtml.html to $(O)\MyGeneratedFile.cs" />
</Target>
```

Now, I wish to create a Nuget package (.NetCore) that achieves similar functionality as projectA (i.e somehow be able to consume this new package in a different netcore application and autogenerate the files- in a similar way projectB is able to use ProjectA's exe to generate the files). As I understand, .NET Core project would create a dll (not an exe); what is the way of using this dll to achieve what I want?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you wish to add a dll at runtime?

Comment: @Max, I wish to consume a nuget package that'll help generate some classes in runtime (these classes are used in the application)

Comment: If you just want to install an existing NuGet package use the `NuGet Package Manager` which is a built-in tool in Visual Studio. If you wish to create a NuGet Package that you can install in your own projects then search the web, there are hundreds of guides. Alternatively you can just add a reference to a DLL in your project.

Comment: Edit: I want those files to be generated in compile time. And it's not an existing package, I want to create one. I can create a package, yes but can we (how?) use a dll to generate files (the way the .Net framework project I mentioned at the beginning of my question does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **.NET Core** is a cross platform framework. This DLL file works across all platforms that are supported by the .NET Core runtime (Windows, Linux, and macOS). This is known as "framework dependent" deployment.

For your case there are 2 options :

1. To run any `.dll` of **.NET Core** application , command `dotnet yourProject.dll` is used.

Part of `projectB.csproj` will look like this:

```
<Target Name="_EX_MyGenerateFile_cs" Inputs="MyHtml.html" Outputs="$(O)\MyGeneratedFile.cs" Condition="'$(BuildingOutOfProcess)' != 'False' AND '$(BuildingProject)' == 'True'" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" Command="dotnet <path to projectA dll> MyHtml.html $(O)\MyGeneratedFile.cs" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" Command="if errorlevel 1 echo $(ERR_MSG) Unable to compile MyHtml.html to $(O)\MyGeneratedFile.cs" />
</Target>
```

2. If you really want exe file, generate exe file using a [Self-Contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) deployment.

This will create an output that contains its own copy of the .NET Core runtime and an `yourProject.exe` file.
*Con of this approach:*

1. It increases the size of the published application.
2. It needs to be updated when new versions of the runtime are released.
3. The resulting application only works on the published operating system published.